# How to customize Product Carousel rendering in the Smartedit?

Tags: angularjs, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

We are facing an issue with the SmartEdit in our Hybris 2105 implementation. Specifically, we have recently added a product carousel to the homepage through SmartEdit. While we can successfully edit and add the carousel, it is not consistently displaying in the SmartEdit slot, particularly in `advance edit` and `preview modes`. Instead, we sometimes only see a pencil icon when hovering over the slot.

Here are what we have tried:

- Hybris version: 2105
- We have already attempted setting up an out-of-the-box (OOTB) site, where the carousel works flawlessly. However, the issue persists in our custom implementation.
- We have also tried creating a custom decoder for the carousel component, but this hasn't resolved the problem.

We are seeking guidance on identifying the potential causes for this issue and any suggestions for resolving it. Any assistance or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!